# Is this suitable for Linq GroupBy?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Dictionary :

```
      Dictionary<Project,List<User>> dictionary,
```

every Project has a group of Users.

I want to retrieve organize this data such that all the projects with similar users are arranged into this kind of data structure :

```
      List<Tuple<List<Project>,List<User>>>
```

I don't even know where to start. I've been fighting with this for days.

Comment: With similar users you mean projects having the same users in their subcollection?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. Projects that have the same users in heir subcollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists of users are the key by which you should group. In the `GroupBy()` you could use a comparer like this one:

```
public class ListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        return x.OrderBy(u => u).SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(u => u));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

BTW: The comparer is on Lists and not on IEnumerables, otherwise for each comparison the compared objects should be enumerated over and over.

Comment: You might want to follow [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948019/linq-implementation-of-cartesian-product-with-pruning) for a more robust comparer.

Comment: I'd like to delete this answer because it's not good. But it's accepted so it can't be deleted. The GetHashCode method doesn't make sense. It should match the `Equals` method but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best would be to flatten the contents of `dictionary` and query against that.