# Create Combinations according to the position in c# list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list

```
    var list = new List<record>{
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 5, value = "a"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 6, value = "b"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "c"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "d"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "e"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 8, value = "f"},
    new record{ flashid = 450, position = 9, value = "g"}
}
```

I have 3 records with position as 7 with different value. from the above list, I need to create a string for each combination according to the position from 1 to 10. for missing position values we can have any temporary character.
So, the desired output will be

```
["....abcfg.","....abdfg.","....abefg."]
```

we can have any special character in the place of dot.

Thanks

Comment: Please show any work you've done previously, and any research. For instance, this is generally referred to as a cartesian product, as in this question: [Is there a good LINQ way to do a cartesian product?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4073713).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ implementation of Cartesian Product with pruning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948019/linq-implementation-of-cartesian-product-with-pruning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can solve this problem, as described at links from comments to your question, But, at this case, you should do tedious work - to write a lot of repeatable code like:

```
var answer = (from pos1 in list.Where(x => x.position == 1)
              from pos2 in list.Where(x => x.position == 2)
              from pos3 in list.Where(x => x.position == 3)
              ....
              from pos10 in list.Where(x => x.position == 10)
              select pos1.value + pos2.value + pos3.value + ... + pos10.value
             ).ToList();
```

So, each time, when you need to change number of possible positions you should add or remove corresponding lines of code. Instead, you can try [recursive approach](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mB2WzW).  Former solution is not dynamic - you should know number of positions in advance at compile time, whereas second solution can be simple tuned at run time via `limit` variable changing.

```
static int limit = 10;

static void Recursive(record record, List<string> bag, 
    Stack<record> stack, List<record> list)
{
    stack.Push(record);
    if (record.position == limit)
    {
        var temp = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in stack)
            temp.Insert(0, item.value);
        bag.Add(temp.ToString());
    }
    else            
        foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.position == record.position + 1))
            Recursive(item, bag, stack, list);
    stack.Pop();            
}

static List<string> Solve(List<record> list)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        if (!list.Any(x => x.position == i))
             list.Add(new record { position = i, value = "." });

    var bag = new List<string>();
    var stack = new Stack<record>();
    foreach (var record in list.Where(x => x.position == 1))
        Recursive(record, bag, stack, list);

    return bag;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var list = new List<record>
{
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 5, value = "a"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 6, value = "b"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "c"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "d"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 7, value = "e"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 8, value = "f"},
    new record { flashid = 450, position = 9, value = "g"}
};

var answer = Solve(list);       
Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(", ", answer) + "]");       
//output: [....abcfg., ....abdfg., ....abefg.]
```

Comment: Thanks @Slava. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a pure LINQ solution you can try the following. First of all extend your record list so that it contains each missing position:

```
var extendedList = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .GroupJoin(list, n => n, r => r.position, (n, g) => g
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new record { flashid = 450, position = n, value = "." }));
```

This basically goes through range from 1 to 10 and for each number corresponding to position matches and groups records. If a group doesn't contain any matching value so that's when a position is missing there is created a default record with temporary character. So the result looks like this:

```
record[10][] 
{ 
    record[] 
    { 
        record { flashid=450, position=1, value="." } 
    },
    (...)
    record[] 
    { 
        record { flashid=450, position=5, value="a" } 
    },
    (...)
    record[] 
    { 
        record { flashid=450, position=7, value="c" },
        record { flashid=450, position=7, value="d" },
        record { flashid=450, position=7, value="e" } 
    },
    (...)
},
```

Now to generate all possible values you can try this:

```
var result = extendedList
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat("", 1), (a, c) => a
        .SelectMany(b => c
            .Select(d => b + d.value)));
```

Each `Aggregate` iteration transforms sequence of words into another sequence of words with added single character from characters group in current position. So it goes like this:

```
0. {""}
1. {"."}
2. {"."}
3. {".."}
4. {"..."}
5. {"....a"}
6. {"....ab"}
7. {"....abc", "....abd", "....abe"}
8. {"....abcf", "....abdf", "....abef"}
9. {"....abcfg", "....abdfg", "....abefg"}
10. {"....abcfg.", "....abdfg.", "....abefg."}
```

You can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCgYFP